# Using python code to run ptraj file

Tags: python, dynamic, command-line

I am running a watershell ptraj file on a coordinate file to find distances of salt ions to a specific atom. I have made the watershell command and I am attempting to write a python code that can run the watershell for a range of values. the command is as follows:

```
for xi in range(0, 25, 0.2):
    x = xi
    y = xi + 0.2
    file = 'file1'+str(xi)+'.dat'
    command = 'watershell :141-182@C1 output.dat lower xi upper y :183-392@Na+'
    print(x,y)
```

I am getting TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as integer.

Comment: Is there really no closing quote in the string that defines command?  Please post your actual code and the traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry in the actual command there is a closing quote, I must've just left it out on accident. The error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range function won't take a float as a step value; instead you have to use an int.  You can get around this by using a multiplier and then dividing when you need to make use of your variable, try something like this:

```
for xi in range(0, 250, 2):
    x = round(xi / 10.0,1)
    y = round(xi / 10.0,1) + 0.2
    file = 'file1'+str(xi)+'.dat'
    command = 'watershell :141-182@C1 output.dat lower xi upper y :183-392@Na+'
    print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `range(0, 25, 0.2)` is illegal.  The step has to be an integer, so 0.2 is not allowed.  I guess you'll have to use a for loop.